# Long command name for horizontal space ~

Tags: spacing, macros

The short command `\,` has (more or less) the long command equivalent `\thinspace`. - What is the long command for the unbreakable space `~`?

Also, is there a long command for a space which is *just a little bit shorter than a space? (For situations like fig. 1, where `fig\,1` puts the two parts too close and `fig.\@ 1` IMHO is to far from each other.)

Answer (score 12):

`~` is defined by

```
\def~{\nobreakspace{}}
```

so `\nobreakspace`

A word space adds a space defined by the font but a typical value is

```
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
```

so `\hspace{.2em plus .1em minus .1em}` would typically be a smaller, but still stretchy, space.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I had a little look around and found the dimensions `\fontdimen2` et al. So I think a more general approach could be the command `\hspace{0.8\fontdimen2\font plus 0.8\fontdimen3\font minus 0.8\fontdimen4\font}`. If I define a macro with this, I'm set. :-)

Comment: Only remaining question: Is `\hspace` unbreakable as is `\nobreakspace`?

Comment: @halloleo Ah OK I nearly mentioned the font dimens but I thought it might look a bit scary, it's hard to know sometimes:-)

Comment: @halloleo  `\hspace` is breakable (like a word space) `\nobreakspace` is `\leavevmode\nobreak\ ` so you can similarly use `\leavevmode\nobreak\hspace{...}`

Comment: Isn't `\hspace*{...}` unbreakable though?